# Parsing HTML .txt files in Hadoop via MapReduce using Python

Tags: python, parsing, hadoop, mapreduce, mrjob

I am very new to using the Hadoop platform and defining MapReduce functions, and I am having a difficult time trying to understand why this mapper is not working in my MapReduce script. I am trying to parse a collection of pages written as a string in a .txt file where each "line" represents `<page>...</page>`. What is incorrect about this script? Thank you for the help!

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
from mrjob.compat import jobconf_from_env
import lxml
import mwparserfromhell
import heapq
import re

class MRParser(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        bigString = ''.join(re.findall(r'(<text xml:space="preserve">.*</text>)',line))
        root = etree.fromstring(bigString.decode('utf-8'))
        if not(bigString == ''):
            bigString = etree.tostring(root,method='text', encoding = "UTF-8")    
            wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(bigString)
            bigString = wikicode.strip_code()
            yield None, bigString

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(mapper=self.mapper)
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the reducer function. You'll need to pass the line from your mapper as a 'key' (with no values) to the reducer. Try this:

```
def mapper(self, _, line):
    bigString = ''.join(re.findall(r'(<text xml:space="preserve">.*</text>)',line))
    root = etree.fromstring(bigString.decode('utf-8'))
    if not(bigString == ''):
        bigString = etree.tostring(root,method='text', encoding = "UTF-8")    
        wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(bigString)
        bigString = wikicode.strip_code()
        yield bigString, None

def reducer(self, key, values):
    yield key, None

def steps(self):
    return [
        MRStep(mapper=self.mapper, reducer=self.reducer)
    ]
```